# Reducing the bezels surrounding editor in Inellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Please look at the image below. There is so much of wasted space in the vertical columns on the left side of the editor. Can we reduce this wasted space somehow?

[image: screenshot of the editor highlighting the extra space]

Comment: Welcome to SO, I guess you may want to read this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/advanced-editing-procedures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That space is used to display gutter icons so try to disable them:

> Settings > Editor > General > Gutter Icon > uncheck "Show Gutter
>   Icon"